# How do I make a lighter version of a colour using PHP?

Tags: php, colors, rgb, color-scheme, color-palette

Hello fellow earthlings. A quesion about RGB color and its usefulness in a simple tiny php code:

Imagine I have variable `$colorA` containning a valid six char color. say `B1B100`, a greenish natural color. Now If I would like to make a new color from that, which is, say, ten steps lighter thatn that original color, roughly.

```
$colorA = B1B100 // original color
php code with little color engine lightening stuff up goes here
$colorB = ?????? // original color lightened up
```

Is there a php ready function that KNOWS rgb colors something like

***php function RGB ( input color, what to do, output color)***
Where what to do could be +/- 255 values of brightness etc etc.

Is something like this already possible or am I day dreaming?

```
rgb-hsl($colorA, +10, $colorB);
```

If this does not exist, what would be the shortest code for doing this? Suggestions, code or ideas are all answers to me. Thanks.

Comment: Day dreaming? It's midnight, man!

Comment: You are right! But these months its dark throughout the day in The Netherlands so I thought let's just be realistic about it :)

Comment: @Pekka - He's obviously a daydream believer! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890409/change-hue-of-an-image-with-php-gd-library) has a full-blown PHP script that can convert a RGB to a HSL colour, and increase its H component of a HSL colour - it should be trivial to change to increase L instead.

Comment: This is old, but this tool is so freaking amazing for color manipulation I couldn't help but mention it: https://github.com/mikeemoo/ColorJizz-PHP

Answer (score 3):

In general if you want a lighter shade of a particular colour, the most accurate process is to convert from RGB to HSL (or HSV), change the 'L' (or 'V') value which represents lightness, and then convert back to RGB.

This will preserve the "hue", which represents where the colour sits on the spectrum, but change the "tint" (if lightening) or "shade" (if darkening) of that colour.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV for more information.

Comment: You could increment the value, or you could increment the red, green, and blue all by the same amount. Either will have the same effect.

Comment: @erisco - they have to be changed _in proportion_, not by the same absolute amount.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that some people don't understand the superiority of grayscale colour themes. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does have a couple image manipulation libraries.  Either [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

EDIT: I jumped the gun, these libraries do not have direct PHP color manipulation functions - I honestly assumed they did of a sort after seeing a lot of the things they can do with images via PHP.  They do accomplish a lot of cool things.  [Here's](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/) one guy's example.

Comment: But none of them offers calculating a lighter colour for a RGB colour value.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion +1, I went on those tho links, and since Im not an expert/genius, I could not find my way there... I guesse those are more for image manipulation and way too complex for my little light-colorish daydreaming... anywayz I guesse I had too colorful/artistic expectations on PHP having read-at-hand rgb solutions...

Answer (score 0):

On this website:  http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=586223  they are talking about this code which is originally made by opensource Drupal. Seems to work fine in PHP!?

Now, how do I now indermingle myself with this code and change the lightness of an HSL value, before its outputted as RGB again?

```
<?php
### RGB >> HSL
function _color_rgb2hsl($rgb) {
  $r = $rgb[0]; $g = $rgb[1]; $b = $rgb[2];
  $min = min($r, min($g, $b)); $max = max($r, max($g, $b));
  $delta = $max - $min; $l = ($min + $max) / 2; $s = 0;
  if ($l > 0 && $l < 1) {
    $s = $delta / ($l < 0.5 ? (2 * $l) : (2 - 2 * $l));
  }
  $h = 0;
  if ($delta > 0) {
    if ($max == $r && $max != $g) $h += ($g - $b) / $delta;
    if ($max == $g && $max != $b) $h += (2 + ($b - $r) / $delta);
    if ($max == $b && $max != $r) $h += (4 + ($r - $g) / $delta);
    $h /= 6;
  } return array($h, $s, $l);
}

### HSL >> RGB
function _color_hsl2rgb($hsl) {
  $h = $hsl[0]; $s = $hsl[1]; $l = $hsl[2];
  $m2 = ($l <= 0.5) ? $l * ($s + 1) : $l + $s - $l*$s;
  $m1 = $l * 2 - $m2;
  return array(_color_hue2rgb($m1, $m2, $h + 0.33333),
               _color_hue2rgb($m1, $m2, $h),
               _color_hue2rgb($m1, $m2, $h - 0.33333));
}

### Helper function for _color_hsl2rgb().
function _color_hue2rgb($m1, $m2, $h) {
  $h = ($h < 0) ? $h + 1 : (($h > 1) ? $h - 1 : $h);
  if ($h * 6 < 1) return $m1 + ($m2 - $m1) * $h * 6;
  if ($h * 2 < 1) return $m2;
  if ($h * 3 < 2) return $m1 + ($m2 - $m1) * (0.66666 - $h) * 6;
  return $m1;
}

### Convert a hex color into an RGB triplet.
function _color_unpack($hex, $normalize = false) {
  if (strlen($hex) == 4) {
    $hex = $hex[1] . $hex[1] . $hex[2] . $hex[2] . $hex[3] . $hex[3];
  } $c = hexdec($hex);
  for ($i = 16; $i >= 0; $i -= 8) {
    $out[] = (($c >> $i) & 0xFF) / ($normalize ? 255 : 1);
  } return $out;
}

### Convert an RGB triplet to a hex color.
function _color_pack($rgb, $normalize = false) {
  foreach ($rgb as $k => $v) {
    $out |= (($v * ($normalize ? 255 : 1)) << (16 - $k * 8));
  }return '#'. str_pad(dechex($out), 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

/* $testrgb = array(0.2,0.75,0.4); //RGB to start with
print_r($testrgb); */
      print "Hex: ";

  $testhex = "#b7b700";
      print $testhex;

  $testhex2rgb = _color_unpack($testhex,true); 
      print "<br />RGB: ";

  var_dump($testhex2rgb);
      print "<br />HSL color module: ";

  $testrgb2hsl = _color_rgb2hsl($testhex2rgb); //Converteren naar HSL

  var_dump($testrgb2hsl);
      print "<br />RGB: ";

  $testhsl2rgb = _color_hsl2rgb($testrgb2hsl); // En weer terug naar RGB    
  var_dump($testhsl2rgb); 
      print "<br />Hex: ";

  $testrgb2hex = _color_pack($testhsl2rgb,true);
  var_dump($testrgb2hex);

?>
```

Comment: just call `_color_rgb2hsl`, take the third element of the result, increase it (L must be <= 1) and then send that array into `_color_hsl2rgb`.  The result of _that_ is what you want.  Use the `_color_unpack` and `_color_pack` functions too if you're using #rrggbb values.