# Find x,y position of a specified colour in an image?

Tags: php, image

Is there any way to get the x,y position of a colour in an image in PHP ?
Eg : In this image

[image]

can I get the starting point,ie the x,y positions of the colour RED.

I need to create an option for the user to change the colour of a particular portion in an image.So if the user wants to change the red colour to blue in this image.I use imagefill() function to change the colour,but it need the x,y coordinates to work.Hope this make sense.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php in a loop, but it'll be very slow for large images

Comment: What do you mean by _starting point_ of _red_? The pixel with the highest _x_ coordinate? or _y_? Also, what is _red_? A color hex value where the _R_ component is higher than both _B_ and _G_?

Comment: @MarcB I think s/he wants the other way round, so it's likely http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorexact.php and/or http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorclosest.php instead

Comment: @gorden: colorexact is for paletted images, though, e.g. a .gif

Comment: what if they are duplicate positions .. do you need all the positions ???

Comment: Actually what I want is, I need to create an option for the user to change the colour of a particular portion in an image.So if the user wants to change the red colour to blue in this image.I use imagefill() function to change the colour,but it need the x,y coordinates to work.Hope this make sense.

Comment: @NidhinzzOwn you are aware that there is different shades of red in the picture, right? See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890409/change-hue-of-an-image-with-php-gd-library solves your problem

Comment: @Gordon.I said red for an example.In practical sense it could be color code or RGB.

Comment: @NidhinzzOwn all the shades of red in your image are a different red. If the user enters 255,0,0 it will only change that particular red, but not the shades of red, so if the user wants to change the parrots head to blue, she would have to enter all the reds in the head. Is that what you want or do you want the user to turn all red to blue at once?

Comment: @Gordon.This image is not the actual one.In my actual image there is not such confusions like in this.I need the user to change exactly that particular colour only.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
// applied only to a PNG images, You can add the other format image loading for Yourself
function changeTheColor($image, $findColor, $replaceColor) {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    $x = imagesx($img);
    $y = imagesy($img);
    $newImg = imagecreate($x, $y);
    $bgColor = imagecolorallocate($newImg, 0, 0, 0); 

    for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $y; $j++) {
            $ima = imagecolorat($img, $i, $j);
            $oldColor = imagecolorsforindex($img, $ima);
            if($oldColor['red'] == $findColor['red'] && $oldColor['green'] == $findColor['green'] && $oldColor['blue'] == $findColor['blue'] && $oldColor['alpha'] == $findColor['alpha'])
                $ima = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImage, $replaceColor['red'], $replaceColor['green'], $replaceColor['blue'], $replaceColor['alpha']);
            }
            imagesetpixel($newImg, $i, $j, $ima);
        }
    }

    return imagepng($newImg);
}
```

We are expecting here that `$findColor` and `$replaceColor` are arrays with this structure:

```
$color = array(
    'red' => 0,
    'green' => 0,
    'blue' => 0,
    'alpha' => 0,
);
```

Didn't try the code but it at least should point You the right way. It loops through every pixel, check the color at that pixel and if it is the one we are looking for, replaces it with the `$replaceColor`. If not, the very same color is then placed into the new image at the very same position.

**As it uses two `for` loops it may be very time and memory consumpting on large images.**