# Change hue of an image (Transparent PNG) using PHP GD

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, hue

I referred to answers on [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890409/change-hue-of-an-image-with-php-gd-library) question.
And I am currently using following code for hue overlay:

```
function imagehue(&$image, $angle) {
if($angle % 360 == 0) return;
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;            
        $alpha = ($rgb & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
        list($h, $s, $l) = rgb2hsl($r, $g, $b);
        $h += $angle / 360;
        if($h > 1) $h--;
        list($r, $g, $b) = hsl2rgb($h, $s, $l);            
        imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $r, $g, $b, $alpha));
    }
  }
}
```

It works good with JPG. But this code doesn't work with transparent PNG images.
This is how I call this function for PNG images:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
**$image = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');**
imagehue($image, 180);
imagejpeg($image);
```

Does anyone know what changes I should make?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use the `imagejpeg` function, use `imagepng` instead.
And if you also want it to work with alpha transparency, add this to your code:

```
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
```