# Change “Saturation” of an image with PHP GD Library?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd, gdlib

There is an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890409/change-hue-of-an-image-with-php-gd-library#answer-1890450) on how to change the **HUE** of an image using PHP-GD library. But I need to know how to change the **SATURATION** of an image using PHP-GD. Here is a copy of the code from the answer which successfully changes the HUE of the image.

```
function imagehue(&$image, $angle) {
    if($angle % 360 == 0) return;
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);

    for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
      for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;            
        $alpha = ($rgb & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
        list($h, $s, $l) = rgb2hsl($r, $g, $b);
        $h += $angle / 360;
        if($h > 1) $h--;
        list($r, $g, $b) = hsl2rgb($h, $s, $l);            
        imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $r, $g, $b, $alpha));
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to take a look at the code of helper functions `rgb2hsl` and `hsl2rgb` please check the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890409/change-hue-of-an-image-with-php-gd-library#answer-1890450). Since `Hue` is one of the parameters of HSL, I thought I could modify the function somehow to get a working solution for Saturation. Despite of limited php skills I had to try but it did not work and produced bizarre results. Here is the modification that I am trying.

---

MODIFIED CODE: **UPDATED** as suggested by @mark

```
function imageSaturation(&$image, $saturationPercentage) {
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);

    for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
        for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;            
            $alpha = ($rgb & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
            list($h, $s, $l) = rgb2hsl($r, $g, $b);         
            $s = $s * (100 + $saturationPercentage ) /100;
            if($s > 1) $s = 1;
            list($r, $g, $b) = hsl2rgb($h, $s, $l);            
            imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $r, $g, $b, $alpha));
        }
    }
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
$image = imagecreatefrompng('rgb.png');
imageSaturation($image, -80);//bring down current image saturation to 80%
imagepng($image);
```

---

**EFFORTS UPDATE** : 
It has been pointed out to me by @Dai that these lines help construct a color code of an individual RGB pixel. So I guess this part can remained unchanged ?

```
$rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;            
$alpha = ($rgb & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
```

In the next line we are simply converting the RGB values to HSL with `rgb2hsl($r, $g, $b);` and assigning it to `list($h, $s, $l)`. The point I am stuck at the moment are these lines.

```
$s += $saturationPercentage / 100;
if($s > 1) $s--;
```

I understand the syntax, but not sure how I handle these or if they are even required. If not an answer helpful hints / suggestions would be great. I am trying the code on [this image](http://postimg.org/image/rhnft3y0n/) to bring down the saturation from 100% to 80%, but I am getting [this image](http://postimg.org/image/xnewygrvv/) as result.

Comment: What is your issue with the last block of code you posted ("where I am really lost"). There isn't any calculations being performed, just bitshifting and bitbasking to extract the byte (0-255) value that represents each pixel color component (Red, Green, Blue, and Opacity).

Comment: @Dai TBH, I have come across these binary concepts for first time and really dont understand what they are doing. I definitely should study about these but really cant afford right now. Please take a look at the updated question.
Do you mean to say that they should remain the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
$s=$s * (100+$saturationPercentage)/100
```

else you are just adding a constant to each value rather than a percentage of the existing value.

Also, where you decrement 1 if your new saturation exceeds 1, you probaly would be better just setting it to 1.0, i.e. fully saturated like this:

```
if($s>1)$s=1
```

otherwise, say the resulting saturation is 1.3 (i.e. very, very saturated) you will make that into `0.3`, i.e. very undersaturated, instead of 1.0 (fully saturated).

So, if `$s` is 0.7, and you add 10%, you will get

```
$s = 0.7 * (100 + 10)/100
$s = 0.7 * 1.1
$s = 0.77
```

Comment: with `imageSaturation($image, 80);` I am looking to decrease the saturation actually, from 100% to 80%. Where else am I wrong ?

Comment: So you would pass `-20`, or change your code to `$s *= $saturationPercentage/100`

Comment: I see the problem now - your image is palletised, not true colour. Try calling `imagepalettetotruecolor($image)` after you load the image as a quick fix. For a proper solution, look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepalettetotruecolor.php. Basically, when you do your bit-shifting to get the `$r`, `$g` and `$b`, you are getting zeroes for `$r` and `$g` and the index into the palette for `$b` rather than what you expect.

Comment: This works 100%. Thank you for your time. Please take a look at the FINAL update to modified code one last time, which includes all your suggestions, and please point out if there are still any mistakes. Here is what I understand. I can call -100 if I need to completely desaturate an image and I think it is pointless to be calling any value beyond 100. Any advice ?

Comment: Glad it worked out! I took another look and I think you are pretty much *"correct"* now. It is perfectly legitimate to add saturation - sometimes people want to add some *pop* to washed out pictures.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier and faster solution to decrease the color saturation:

- create a black and white clone of the image
- mix the black and white clone with the original

The code is something like this:

```
function imageSaturation($im, $percentage) /* $percentage to be between 0 and 100 */
{
    $width  = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im);     
    $im2  = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopy($im2, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    imagefilter($im2, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagecopymerge($im, $im2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, 100-$percentage);
    imagedestroy($im2);
}
```